# Object reference not set to an instance of an object strange behaviour with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

This is very bizarre.

The following code throws a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`:

```
var members = db.Members.Where(
    a => 
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchEmail) 
            || (a.Email ?? "").ToUpper().Contains(searchEmail.ToUpper()));
```

where `db` is a `DataContext` and `searchEmail` is a string, which in this case is set to `null`.

The code should return all `Members` because the first half of the `||` returns true, however, I am getting the above exception.

Strangely if I change the code to:

```
var members = db.Members.Where(
    a => 
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchEmail) 
            || (a.Email ?? "").ToUpper().Contains((searchEmail ?? "").ToUpper()));
```

no exception is thrown! Presumably that means that `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is evaluating `false` when clearly it is evaluating `true` unless there is something about `IQueryable`'s implementation of `Where`?

---

### Update

[Habib's answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323361/1185053). For other people reading this, my solution to get around the limitation Habib explained was:

```
var members = db.Members.AsQueryable();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchEmail))
    members = members.Where(a => a.Email.ToUpper()
                        .Contains(searchEmail.ToUpper()));
```

Comment: At first glance, the culprit could be a null a.Email, which would make ToUpper throw that exception

Comment: I think Linq executes all instructions inside its lamba expression. It's different from any comparison like with "IF".

Comment: That would still throw in the second example, and his point is that the short circuiting `||` operator should make the right hand of the statement not evaluate when the left side is true.

Comment: @SystemDown Actually I tried that before and still the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This LINQ expression translates in to SQL Query, it **doesn't do short circuiting**  as expected. That is why you are getting th exception.

[SQL-CLR Type Mismatches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386909.aspx)

> C# specifies short circuit semantics based on lexical order of
>   operands for logical operators && and ||. SQL on the other hand is
>   targeted for set-based queries and therefore provides more freedom for
>   the optimizer to decide the order of execution.